# Clicking on entire element to register radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, radio-button, label

I would like to be able to click on the whole element, rather than just the radio button and text, in order to register the value associated with the radio button.

```
<div class='btn'>
<input id = '4' class='btn4' type="radio" name='1' value='' >    
<label for = '4' class="label4">Question populated from jQuery goes here
</label></div>
```

When I wrap the input with the label, I lose the text that jQuery puts inside the element.

The function I have to populate the text is...

```
function populateQuestion(index) {
if (currentQuestion <=9){
$('.q_question').html(questionsArray[index]['question']);
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    $('.jumbotron').html('');
    $('.btn' + (i + 1)).val(questionsArray[index]['choices'][i]).prop('checked', false);
  $('.label' + (i + 1)).html(questionsArray[index]['choices'][i]);
}
} else{ quizComplete(correctAnswers)}
}
populateQuestion(currentQuestion);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting little problem.  I tried to do it in one line of jQuery, but quickly realized that since the elements that were changing we located inside the container, trying to click them would reset them (effectively making themselves unclickable).  The solution was to add an invisible pseudo element on top of the container in CSS so that you couldn't actually click the radio (or label).

```js
$('div.btn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).children('input').prop('checked', !$(this).children('input').prop('checked'));
})
```

```css
.btn {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
}
.btn::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='btn'>
  <input id='4' class='btn4' type="radio" name='1' value=''>
  <label for='4' class="label4">Question populated from jQuery goes here
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may register a click event for the outer div and execute whatever code you want to do .

```
$(function(){

  $("div.btn").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     alert("clicked");
     var _this=$(this);
     var radio = _this.find("input[type='radio']");
     //Do something now
     alert('id:'+radio.attr("id"));  //Id of radio button
     alert('value:'+radio.val());    //value of radio button
  });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/lewezen/edit?html,css,js,console,output) is a working sample.